# Cannot start grabserial on Raspberry pi boot

Tags: linux, bash, raspberry-pi

I have a problem with starting a bash script data.sh, which is using *grabserial* to get data from serial input and store them in the .txt file (if it doesn't exist, it creates it):

```
#!/bin/bash
grabserial -v -d /dev/ttyAMA0 -b 9600 -w 8 -p N -s 1 -o /home/pi/serialLog.txt
```

After booting there is not however any serialLog.txt file created, therefore I think it doesn't run properly (manually running the script creates the .txt file immedeately). My goal is to run that script on the background (as I could have achieved manually by starting it in screen and then detach the window). I tried to write the path of the script to /etc/rc.local (of course also set up the privileges of data.sh to 755) like that:

```
/home/pi/data.sh &
exit 0
```

Because my grabserial should run infinitely, I have put the & behind, which if I understand it correctly, makes fork and next command doesn't need the previous one to be finished.

If I try another code in bash not using grabserial, it works perfectly. Could you please tell me, whether I am doing anything wrong using grabserial? Thank you, Kaki

Comment: There's a possibility that your script runs on boot but your `/home` isn't mounted yet. There's also a possibility the script runs before serial port is ready and the script just bailed out. There's plenty of possibility but lack of error message handling is preventing an easy trace of the problem.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. /home is mounted in time, I have tried to start another script writing to /home/pi/file.txt on boot parallely (added row `python /home/pi/test.py &` ) and the second script executes normally. Also have tried to save everything that's normally printed in console to a file as a error log, but it doesn't work, nothing is printed unless I start the bash script manually.

Comment: I suspect the oroblem is that `grabserial` is not on the PATH when run from `/etc/rc.local` because that doesn't go through your login profile setup. Try adding the full path, e.g. `/usr/local/bin/grabserial... `

Comment: I too do not see anything wrong with your use of `grabserial`. Note that there are a few ways you might launch something at boot time, and without knowing which distro of Linux you're using, it's difficult to recommend a "best" option. You might also consider using the special `@reboot` time if your `cron` supports it. Or perhaps launching `grabserial` in a detached GNU Screen session, with `screen -d -m /path/to/grabserial -options`. At any rate, it sounds like your issue isn't so much programming as it is system administration.

Answer (score 0):

the filename must be between hyphens:
-o "filename"

Comment: -Hyphens-? Or "double quotes"?

Comment: Seems unlikely.